# Python File Reading & Writing

Tags: python, file

So I need to write a program that reads a text file, and copies its contents to another file. I then have to add a column at the end of the text file, and populate that column with an int that is calculated using the function calc_bill. I can get it to copy the contents of the original file to the new one, but I cannot seem to get my program to read in the ints necessary for calc_bill to run. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the first 3 lines of the text file I am reading from:

```
CustomerID  Title   FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    Customer Type   
1   Mr. Orlando N.  Gee Residential     297780  302555
2   Mr. Keith   NULL    Harris  Residential     274964  278126
```

It is copying the file exactly as it is supposed to to the new file. What is not working is writing the bill_amount (calc_bill)/ billVal(main) to the new file in a new column. Here is the expected output to the new file:

```
CustomerID  Title   FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    Customer Type   Company Name    Start Reading   End Reading  BillVal
1   Mr. Orlando N.  Gee Residential     297780  302555       some number
2   Mr. Keith   NULL    Harris  Residential     274964  278126    some number
```

And here is my code:

```
def main():
    file_in = open("water_supplies.txt", "r")
    file_in.readline()
    file_out = input("Please enter a file name for the output:")
    output_file = open(file_out, 'w')
    lines = file_in.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        lines = [line.split('\t')]
        #output_file.write(str(lines)+ "\n")
        billVal = 0
        c_type = line[5]
        start = int(line[7])
        end = int(line[8])
        billVal = calc_bill(c_type, start, end)
        output_file.write(str(lines)+ "\t" + str(billVal) + "\n")


def calc_bill(customer_type, start_reading, end_reading):
    price_per_gallon = 0

    if customer_type == "Residential":
        price_per_gallon = .012

    elif customer_type == "Commercial":
        price_per_gallon = .011

    elif customer_type == "Industrial":
        price_per_gallon = .01

    if start_reading >= end_reading:
        print("Error: please try again")

    else:
        reading = end_reading - start_reading

    bill_amount = reading * price_per_gallon
    return bill_amount
main()
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: There is no error when compiling. The current output to the newly generated text file is in the second block of "code" in the original question.

Comment: You've written that that's the expected output. You might want to fix that :)

Comment: Oh my bad, I messed up. The current output is the first block. Sorry about that :)

Comment: I just noticed you're overwriting your `lines` variable on the first of that for loop - you might want to pick a different name... In fact, I'm pretty sure you meant to save the variable `line` rather than `lines`?

Comment: Also, it's easier to just use the csv module to handle this. Also, for your function, you can just use a dictionary instead of putting so many ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the issues mentioned above, but here is a small change to your `main()` method that works correctly.

```
def main():
    file_in = open("water_supplies.txt", "r")
    # skip the headers in the input file, and save for output
    headers = file_in.readline()
    # changed to raw_input to not require quotes
    file_out = raw_input("Please enter a file name for the output: ")
    output_file = open(file_out, 'w')
    # write the headers back into output file
    output_file.write(headers)
    lines = file_in.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # renamed variable here to split
        split = line.split('\t')
        bill_val = 0
        c_type = split[5]
        start = int(split[6])
        end = int(split[7])
        bill_val = calc_bill(c_type, start, end)
        # line is already a string, don't need to cast it
        # added rstrip() to remove trailing newline
        output_file.write(line.rstrip() + "\t" + str(bill_val) + "\n")
```

Note that the `line` variable in your loop includes the trailing newline, so you will need to strip that off as well if you're going to write it to the output file as-is. Your `start` and `end` indices were off by 1 as well, so I changed to `split[6]` and `split[7]`.

It is a good idea to not require the user to include the quotes for the filename, so keep that in mind as well. An easy way is to just use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Sample input file (from OP):

```
CustomerID      Title   FirstName       MiddleName      LastName        Customer Type
1       Mr.     Orlando N.      Gee     Residential     297780  302555
2       Mr.     Keith   NULL    Harris  Residential     274964  278126

$ python test.py
Please enter a file name for the output:test.out
```

Output (test.out):

```
1       Mr.     Orlando N.      Gee     Residential     297780  302555  57.3
2       Mr.     Keith   NULL    Harris  Residential     274964  278126  37.944
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still seem to be getting the same output on the newly generated file.

Comment: See my edits. I added the input file I'm using from your original question, as well as the output generated when I run the above code.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. My only question is, what do you mean about the input() function forcing users to use quotes?

Comment: Typically if you just use `input()`, Python will actually try to execute the text the user enters, so when I was running your code it would give me an error if I didn't use quotes. `raw_input()` basically just returns the text entered as-is, instead of the Python interpretation of the text.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you. One last question: If I wanted to keep the first line from the original text file (the column headers), how would I do that?

Comment: since you are doing a `readline()` at the beginning to skip the headers, just store that in a variable, then write that back to the output_file before your loop... I will edit to include that

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things. The inconsistent spacing in your column names makes counting the actual columns a bit confusing, but I believe there are 9 column names there. However, each of your rows of data have only 8 elements, so it looks like you've got an extra column name (maybe "CompanyName"). So get rid of that, or fix the data.

Then your "start" and "end" variables are pointing to indexes 7 and 8, respectively. However, since there are only 8 elements in the row, I think the indexes should be 6 and 7.

Another problem could be that inside your for-loop through "lines", you set "lines" to the elements in that line. I would suggest renaming the second "lines" variable inside the for-loop to something else, like "elements".

Aside from that, I'd just caution you about naming consistency. Some of your column names are camel-case and others have spaces. Some of your variables are separated by underscores and others are camel-case.

Hopefully that helps. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in handling your variables, both in the same line:

```
    lines = [line.split()]
```

- You put this into your `lines` variable, which is the entire file contents.  You just lost the rest of your input data.
- You made a new list-of-list from the return of `split`.

Try this line:

```
    line = line.split()
```

I got reasonable output with that change, once I make a couple of assumptions about your placement of tabs.

Also, consider *not* overwriting a variable with a different data semantic; it confuses the usage.  For instance:

```
    for record in lines:
    line = record.split()
```